# If one of TEX’s internal parameters is changed within a group, the previous contents of that parameter will be restored when the group ends in TeX?

Tags: tex-core, grouping

I see this sentence on page 21 of the book **The TeXbook**, but I can't understand it. May you show me an example and explain it to me?

> If one of TEX’s internal parameters is changed within a group, the previous contents of that parameter will be restored when the group ends in TeX?.

I think the previous contents of that parameter needn't restore as it never be changed by the parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider an internal parameter such as `\baselineskip`

If you do

```
\baselineskip=100pt
{ \baselineskip=5pt }
\showthe\baselineskip
```

then you will see that `\baselineskip`  is 5pt within the group, but restored to 100pt at the group end.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you consider an internal parameter. For many of them, the behavior is to respect grouping. But there are a few subtleties.

For instance, hyphenation assignments are always global, so you can't say

```
{\hyphenation{some-long-word}<text of a paragraph containing somelongword>\par}
```

and expect that TeX forgets the given hyphenation exception when the group ends.

Similarly font assignments are always global, by which the TeXbook means

```
\fontdimen<number><font>=<dimen>
\hyphenchar<font>=<number>
\skewchar<font>=<number>
```

where `<font>` is a font selector (see the relevant part in the TeXbook).

Box size assignments are a bit weird in this respect. Consider

```
This is TeX, Version 3.141592653 (TeX Live 2023) (preloaded format=tex)
**\relax

*\newbox\test

*\setbox\test=\hbox{test}

*\showthe\wd\test
> 16.16669pt.
<*> \showthe\wd\test
                    
? 

*\begingroup\wd\test=100pt\endgroup

*\showthe\wd\test
> 100.0pt.
<*> \showthe\wd\test
```

but the seemingly similar session

```
This is TeX, Version 3.141592653 (TeX Live 2023) (preloaded format=tex)
**\relax

*\newbox\test

*\setbox\test=\hbox{test}

*\showthe\wd\test
> 16.16669pt.
<*> \showthe\wd\test
                    
? 

*\begingroup\setbox\test=\hbox{different test}\wd\test=100pt\showthe\wd\test
> 100.0pt.
<*> ...fferent test}\wd\test=100pt\showthe\wd\test
                                                  
? 

*\endgroup

*\showthe\wd\test
> 16.16669pt.
<*> \showthe\wd\test
```

has a different result. The assignment of a width to the box register globally affects the *last* incarnation of the box. So in the first session the assignment `\wd\test=100pt` affects the box at the upper level, but in the second session it doesn't.

Also assignments to `\spacefactor` are inherently global. The same for `\prevgraf`, `\deadcycles` and `\insertpenalties`. There are also dimension parameter that are unaffected by grouping, namely

```
\prevdepth  \pagegoal  \pagetotal  \pagestretch  \pagefilstretch
\pagefillstretch  \pagefilllstretch  \pageshrink  \pagedepth
```

that are related to page making.